# How can use Date time picker in angular4 webpack project

Tags: angular, webpack, datetimepicker, angular-material2

I am working angular4 app using webpack. Now I need use datetime picker 
for my requirement. I tried angular4 material and also ng2-datepicker-bootstrap but these gives error and not build app.I have no idea how to use it in webpack project with angular4

How can i use it any suggestion.

I follow this tutorial for my angular4 webpack configuration. 
[angular4 webpack configuration](https://angular.io/guide/webpack)

Thanks

Comment: You need to show us at least your webpack config, if not - no one will be able to help you

Comment: Thanks Fredrik Lundin, I am going to add  webpack config.@ Fredrik Lundin

Comment: Can you also show/explain how you import the date pickers? Are you including them in the NgModule etc? What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: I follow this tutorial for https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview and i import  app.module.ts file 
import {MdDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
    imports:[MdDatepickerModule]
})

Comment: Did you add `import '@angular/material';` to your `vendor.ts` file?

Comment: yes I did it also@Fredrik Lundin

Comment: Please add more info to your question instead of in comments or by just referring to tutorials. Add your config, your NgModule and the error message you are getting. That will help us help you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use an INPUT TYPE DATE, that will give you a datetime picker.

```
<input type=date>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp